# How does SO maintain ever growing list of questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Just kind of wondering, does SO ever discard questions that are too old or questions that are asked poorly? Since the questions on SO and other stackexchange sites will only grow larger, wouldn't you eventually run out of space on the physical hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...does SO ever discard questions ... that are asked poorly?

So much.  So very, very much.

Seriously though, and more to your point, check out some of the old blog articles like [Stack Overflow Network Configuration](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-network-configuration/) and [Database Upgrade](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/database-upgrade/) for a peek at the underlying architecture.  They can always add more database servers.

Comment: thank you, will take a look at that :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a random (not the most cost effective) hard drive on Neweegg for $180, for 1.5 TB. That's about $0.12 per gigabyte of storage. They're not going to run out of space on physical hardware, especially because the storage of a question probably costs VERY little space.